# Pandas If row value contains items from a list as substrings, add new colum with values present on substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If row value contains text from a list as substrings, I would like to add a new column on my df with the values matching the list.

INPUT DATAFRAME:

```
1      ['a','b','d']
2      ['a','e','l']
3      ['a','b']
4      ['a','x','t','a','b','A']
```

This is my list:

```
list=['a','b','A']
```

output expected:

```
index  tech                         final_tech
1      ['a','b','d']                a, b
2      ['a','e','l']                a
3      ['a','b']                    a, b
4      ['a','x','t','a','b','A']    a, b, A
```

Any idea how to I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: For the dataframe with structure cells, you should include the output of `df.to_dict()` instead of the output of `print(df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given OP's dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tech': [['a','b','d'],['a','e','l'],['a','b'],['a','x','t','a','b','A']]})
```

And the list

```
list=['a','b','A']
```

One can achieve OP's goal using [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and a lambda function as follows (`set` will make sure a specific string appears only once)

```
df['final_tech'] = df['tech'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set([i for i in x if i in list])))

[Out]:
                 tech final_tech
0           [a, b, d]        a,b
1           [a, e, l]          a
2              [a, b]        a,b
3  [a, x, t, a, b, A]      A,a,b
```

If one doesn't care if the strings appear duplicated in `final_tech`, then simply use the following (for reference check the last row and compare to the previous output)

```
df['final_tech'] = df['tech'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([i for i in x if i in list]))

[Out]:

                 tech final_tech
0           [a, b, d]        a,b
1           [a, e, l]          a
2              [a, b]        a,b
3  [a, x, t, a, b, A]    a,a,b,A
```